# Script to delete jobs more then 8 days

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a script to go into that workspace and delete jobs that are more than 8 days.

The script is mean to go in to the sub-directories (folder inside folder and inside it jobs) and delete anything more than 8 days

It delete some jobs in some directories and leave some without deleting.

**Error shows: cannot delete, directory is not empty**

```
!/bin/bash

directory="/home/jenkins/workspace/"

cd $directory && find . -mtime +8 -delete
echo $directory deleted
```

**Your input is highly welcome
Thanks**

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says. If you have a directory with an mtime more than 8 days old but something _under_ that directory has a newer mtime, then it can't be deleted, and will have the message described. This is not a bug; it's everything working just as it's supposed to.

Comment: Hard to tell. Since -delete implies -depth, so content is processed first, and only then containing dirs, There are many reason why a dir could be nonemty tho.

Comment: There are many directories inside a directory and many files inside those directories. The aim is to clean any directores and files more than 8 days

Comment: Yes, but you can't always do that. If a >8 days dir contains a <8 days file, you can't delete it. So you need other conditions. For exemple, as Charles suggested, delete >8days files and then delete >8days EMPTY directories

Comment: Doesn't Jenkins have built-in functionality to delete old stuff?

Answer (score 1):

The logic that's correct for files isn't also correct for directories: a directory can be older than 8 days but still be undeletable (because it has files under it that were last modified less than 8 days ago).

The easy thing to do (because it takes order-of-operations questions out of play) is to split this into two separate `find` calls, first deleting old files, then deleting empty directories:

```
find "$directory" -mtime +8 -type f -delete
find "$directory" -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why you may end up trying to delete non empty directories

- Maybe (main possible reason, depending on the unknown structure of what you call jobs) you have >8 days old dir containing <8 days files (the file cannot be <8 days since creating a file in the dir should change that dir mtime. But it could be a >8 days file that has been recently updated. Then dir mtime is unchanged)
- Maybe you have a new file in a old sub sub dir of an old directory. So, can't delete the dir
- Or permissions making impossible to empty a dir. Or special files...

But, well. You can't delete an empty dir. And from what you've shown nothing prove that there can't be new (undeleted) files in an old dir. And in that case your script will try to -delete that dir.